# Find total unique counter based on unique id and date - MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregate

I'm trying to count all and unique events on daily based based on the following data shape:

```
{
    username: "jack",
    events: [
     {
       eventType: "party",
       createdAt: "2022-01-23T10:26:11.214Z",
       visitorInfo: {
            visitorId: "87654321-0ebb-4238-8bf7-87654321"
           }
     },
     {
       eventType: "party",
       createdAt: "2022-01-23T10:26:11.214Z",
       visitorInfo: {
            visitorId: "87654321-0ebb-4238-8bf7-87654321"
           }
     },
     {
       eventType: "party",
       createdAt: "2022-01-23T10:26:11.214Z",
       visitorInfo: {
            visitorId: "01234567-0ebb-4238-8bf7-01234567"
           }
     },
     {
       eventType: "party",
       createdAt: "2022-01-30T10:26:11.214Z",
       visitorInfo: {
            visitorId: "12345678-0ebb-4238-8bf7-12345678"
           }
     },
    {
       eventType: "party",
       createdAt: "2022-01-30T10:16:11.214Z",
       visitorInfo: {
            visitorId: "12345678-0ebb-4238-8bf7-12345678"
           }
     }
       ]

    }
```

I'm trying to count events (all and unique ones based on visitorId) on date (daily).
This is what I have so far (thanks to @R2D2's guide on the approach):

```
 Event.aggregate([
  { $match: { username: 'jack' } },

  { $unwind: "$events" },

  {
    $project: {
      total: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: ["$events.eventType", "party"],
          },
          1,
          0,
        ],
      },

    unique: { // where I'm stuck. I need to count unique events based on visitorId on current date.
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: ["$events.eventType", "party"],
          },
          1,
          0,
        ],
      },

      date: "$events.createdAt",
    },
  },

  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" },
      },

    
      total: {
        $sum: "$total",
      },

      uniqueTotal: {
        $sum: "$unique",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      date: "$_id",
      total: 1,
      uniqueTotal: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "0",
      dateAndEventFrequency: {
        $push: "$$ROOT",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      dateAndEventFrequency: 1,
    },
  },
]);
```

I tried using `$addToSet` but it's not used with `$project` (it works with `$group`).
Any new approach is welcome based on the data shape and the desired result I'm expecting. I used `$project` because I was already using it.

Basically what I'm hoping to get in the end:

```
dateAndEventFrequency: [
    {
    _id: "2022-01-23",
    uniqueTotal: 2,
    total: 3,
    date: "2022-01-23",
    },
   {
    _id: "2022-01-30",
    uniqueTotal: 1,
    total: 2,
    date: "2022-01-30",
    },
]
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

first group by `date` and `visitorId` together and then do another group just by `date`

you can test it here [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WZGS7spwY9q)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      username: "jack"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$events"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        date: {
          "$dateToString": {
            format: "%Y-%m-%d",
            date: "$events.createdAt"
          }
        },
        "visitorId": "$events.visitorInfo.visitorId",
        
      },
      "count": {
        "$count": {}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.date",
      "uniqueTotal": {
        "$count": {}
      },
      total: {
        "$sum": "$count"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you @sina bariaji, but when trying this approach in Mongoose in Nodejs, I'm getting
"unknown group operator '$count'".

I tried replacing count with sum:
     {
        "$sum": 1
      }
but it doesn't seem to be the equivalent. Any ideas? :)

Comment: you sure `sum: { "$sum": 1 }` did'nt work? i checked it and im getting the same result [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vv6BMJNdAMs)

Comment: Fixed it, thanks! btw, how would this work for different 'eventType' though? This solution only get total with unique visitorId, but doesn't take the event type into consideration. E.g. getting total count for eventType 'party' and eventType 'meeting'. Thanks again @sina bariaji

Comment: yw, i'm not sure what do you exactly want but you can add eventType to the `$group` to group by all values inside it [like this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/spsoQ_I_-V2), but if you jsut want to get `meeting` and `pary` just add a `$match` before the `$group` and filter by eventTypes you want [like this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/psO9twQMTHy)

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but I want to aggregate the totals and unique events on the dates (same object). I actually asked it in a new question as i thought this is diverging from original question. I would appreciate it if you check it out, I tried to explain it better there https://stackoverflow.com/q/71080000/16957532. Thanks! @sina bariaji